# Populate from other table if empty

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, TableA and TableB. I want to populate TableC with values from TableA, and if it does not exist in TableA then populate from TableB for example

TableA

```
 ID    Value
 AA      1
 AC      1
 AE      1
 AF      1
```

TableB

```
 ID    Value
 AB      1
 AD      1
 AE      1
 AF      1
```

TableC

```
 ID    Value
 AA      1
 AB      1
 AC      1
 AD      1
 AE      1
 AF      1
```

I tried using this query, but I only get results in TableA

```
 Select 
          isnull(nullif(a.ID,' '), b.ID) ID,
          cast(isnull(nullif(a.val,' '), b.val) as float) as Val

into TableC
from TableA a
FULL JOIN TableB b
ON a.ID = b.ID
```

Comment: Always value = 1?

Comment: I can't replicate your failure: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=02fd552b1675d62221bf4a5af2c1e01f)

Comment: @jarlh not always. I put 1 for simplicity

Comment: Different values is a different problem... Which answer do you want - an answer for all 1's, or one for different values?

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is in your NULLIF calls, you're comparing a.id to a space, and a space is not null, so whether or not a.id is null, NULLIF returns something other than null, so the ISNULL call is not returning the value from b.

```
select
    case when a.id is null then b.id else a.id end as id,
    case when a.id is null then b.val else a.val end as val
from
    tableA a
    full join
    tableB b on b.id = a.id
```